# It's possible to have a WHERE clause after a HAVING clause?

Tags: sql, where-clause, having

Is it possible to use a WHERE clause after a HAVING clause?

The first thing that comes to my mind is sub queries, but I'm not sure.

P.S. If the answer is affirmative, could you give some examples?

Comment: Is this a trick/interview question, or do you have a real problem to solve?

Comment: Yes. The question is from an interview.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, not in the same query.

The `where` clause goes before the `having` and the `group by`. If you want to filter out records before the grouping the condition goes in the `where` clause, and if you want to filter out grouped records the condition goes in the `having` clause:

```
select ...
from ...
where ...
group by ...
having ...
```

If neither of those are possible to use for some odd reason, you have to make the query a subquery so that you can put the `where` clause in the outer query:

```
select ...
from (
   select ...
   from ...
   where ...
   group by ...
   having ...
) x
where ...
```

Answer (score 5):

A HAVING clause is just a WHERE clause after a GROUP BY.  Why not put your WHERE conditions in the HAVING clause?

Comment: Conceptually, the HAVING clause is applied after the GROUP BY operation, whereas the WHERE clause is applied before so theoretically there could be optimization by 'filtering' in the WHERE clause. In practice, you will (as always) have to look at how the optimizer handles it e.g. examine the execution plan. Also consider the human reader, who would normally expect to see 'filtering' predicated in the WHERE clause (rather than the join clauses, HAVING clauses, etc).

Answer (score 5):

If it's a trick question, it's possible if the WHERE and the HAVING are not at the same level, as you mentionned, with subquery.

I guess something like that would work

> HAVING value=(SELECT max(value) FROM
>   foo WHERE crit=123)

p.s.: why were you asking?
Do you have a specific problem?

p.s.s: OK silly me, I missed the "interview*" tag...

Answer (score 3):

From SELECT help

> Processing Order of WHERE, GROUP BY,
>   and HAVING Clauses The following steps
>   show the processing order for a SELECT
>   statement with a WHERE clause, a GROUP
>   BY clause, and a HAVING clause:
>
> The FROM clause returns an initial
>   result set.
>
> The WHERE clause excludes rows not
>   meeting its search condition.
>
> The GROUP BY clause collects the
>   selected rows into one group for each
>   unique value in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Aggregate functions specified in the
>   select list calculate summary values
>   for each group.
>
> The HAVING clause additionally
>   excludes rows not meeting its search
>   condition.

So, no you can not.

Answer (score 2):

Within the same scope, answer is no. If subqueries is allowed then you can avoid using `HAVING` entirely.

I think `HAVING` is an anachronism. Hugh Darwen refers to `HAVING` as "The Folly of Structured Queries":

> In old SQL, the `WHERE` clause could not
>   be used on results of aggregation, so
>   they had to invent `HAVING` (with same
>   meaning as `WHERE`):
>
> ```
> SELECT D#, AVG(Salary) AS Avg_Sal
>   FROM Emp
>  GROUP 
>     BY D#
> HAVING AVG(Salary) > 999;
> ```
>
> But would we ever have had `HAVING` if
>   in 1979 one could write:
>
> ```
> SELECT * 
>   FROM (
>         SELECT D#, AVG(Sal) AS Avg_Sal
>           FROM Emp
>          GROUP 
>             BY D# 
>        )
>       AS dummy
> WHERE Avg_Sal > 999;
> ```

I strongly suspect the answer to Darwen's question is no.